# Why are InnoDB's index keys limited to 767 bytes?

Tags: mysql, innodb, index

MySQL's official documentation states [about InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> An index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. The same length limit applies to any index key prefix.

The meaning of this statement is clear to me, however I do not understand the reasons of this limitation, which seems arbitrary (why 767?).
Any pointers?

Comment: Why some other number?

Comment: ...or, why not some other number?

Comment: My guess: `767 = 3*255 + 2`. You can have a column indexed if it is up to `VARCHAR(255)` (when it's using UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks, but that's a consequence of the limitation, not a reason for it. By the way, `VARCHAR` columns of length > 255 can be indexed, just not with a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` index.

Comment: @ypercube's calculation is correct. LoicAG, your are correct to some extent that "that's a consequence of the limitation, not a reason for it". But that's the world of software engineering: you set some limitations (eg one byte for the length of a text) an other limitations are derived from your decisions.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach I understand that ypercube's calculation is correct; however, what I'm interested in here is why the limitation was set to 767 bytes in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. My guess is that MySQL developers set the limit to 767 after they set an arbitrary value (255) for characters columns, considered that that would cover most uses and then calculated what would be needed to index such columns.

Comment: @ypercube ah OK, I got your point now. In that case, why 255 for character columns, and why "+ 2" in "3 * 255 + 2"?

Comment: Varchar columns use extra bytes to store the length of the strings (in bytes). So, for 765 (which is `>=2^8` and `< (2^8)^2` you need 2 more bytes. Now, why 255 was chosen as a reasonable size, I have not a clue.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be linked to the [size of the InnoDB pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> If you reduce the InnoDB page size to 8KB or 4KB by specifying the innodb_page_size option when creating the MySQL instance, the maximum length of the index key is lowered proportionally, based on the limit of 3072 bytes for a 16KB page size. That is, the maximum index key length is 1536 bytes when the page size is 8KB, and 768 bytes when the page size is 4KB.

Thanks to XL on the #mysql IRC chat for the pointer to page sizes. I will update this answer when I find out more about the InnoDB page format and its limitations.

---

**UPDATE**
The quote above applies to the total index key length for a row, whereas my original question was about the index key length for a single-column index. My guess at this point is that the 767-byte limitation is legacy from the time when all pages were 4KB in size, and thus both single-column and multi-column indexes were limited to a total length of 767 (+1?) bytes.
I will update this question again when I have more information about:

- how the page size influences the index key length,
- why there is a 1-byte difference in maximum key length between single-column indexes and multi-column indexes, and
- why the legacy value of 767 bytes (if it is indeed a legacy value) was kept for single-column index key lengths.